# How to structure a Django reusable app

Tags: django, package

I've written a bit of code to add version information to Django models. I'd like to release it out into the wild.

So, what's the best way to structure the project and also package it for distribution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here [are](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/mar/27/reusable-django-apps/) [some](http://ericholscher.com/projects/django-conventions/app/) [hints](http://www.trunat.fr/djangocong/html/).

Answer (score 0):

You should package your app up and upload it to pypi. Follow the guide [here](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html). It's a simple process. Make sure you have documentation, a README and LICENSE. Tests are pretty huge. Most people won't even bother with your app if you don't have tests. [Django Pluggable Patterns](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-pluggable-django-patterns-4900929) is a great talk from Pycon 2011 about best practices for Django apps.